# Catching keystroke during loop in batch

Tags: batch-file, keystroke

As a small training for my batch programming I originally followed the idea to make up a small slotmachine. You can give your coins, the numbers rush through and when you hit a button, the numbers should stop at their current value. If they are all the same, boom, you won the jackpot!

My problem right now is the keystroke capture during the loop. I already thought something like a choice command, but then the program would stop at each loop waiting for keyboard input, not making the game just quite annoying to wait all the time, but as well boring as you could check if you want to hit a specific button to stop.

Another thought was putting

```
set /p foobar=
```

and then simulate an Enter-Stroke with `!SendKeys!` (with everything neccessary in the code), forgetting that the enter yould have been sended after input...

Is there a way to accomplish that in **ONE** batch file? Or do I have to come up with another one to simulate the keystrokes or is there anything else I have missed?

EDIT: To clearify: Is there any command that changes something on keystroke, but runs through if nothing is touched?

Thanks for help in advance!

Greetings

geisterfurz007

Comment: `choice` features switches `/D` and `/C` you might be interested in...

Comment: Oooooh. I misunderstood the help there. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @aschipfl Well this seems to working not as well as I first thought. The problem is basically the delay. When I set `/t 1` it takes way to long for the next loop to go and when I set `/t 0` I have no possibility to input anything.

When trying to set it to 0.5 or 0,5 I get an error telling me that value is not valid. Any suggestion?

Comment: Alright, so you need to borrow some code from other languages, I think; perhaps VBScript, JavaScript, or PowerShell?

Comment: So it is not possible just within a batch file or will it be something like the !SendKeys! including cscript within the code? Unfortunately I am not familiar with any of these... Is it much code to borrow or hard to understand? If it is to much I will just find something else to train.

Comment: With pure batch scripting it's not possible. I was not thinking of `SendKeys`, but I guess there exists something opposite in some other language, which could be used. But just guessing, I never needed anything like that so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create an empty file
cd . > key.txt

rem Start a parallel process that wait for Enter key
rem and add a line to the empty file
start "" /B cmd /C "set /P = & echo line >> key.txt"

set "key="
:wait
   cls
   set "number=%random:~-4%"
   echo %number%
   echo/
   echo Press Enter key to stop the numbers...
   set /P key=< key.txt
if not defined key goto wait

echo The last number is: %number%
```

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous! Works like a charm; thanks a lot!